# SqlDataReader not returning all the rows?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

This is my code:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("My_SQL_Command"))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60000;

    try
    {
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            while (rdr.Read())  // I put a breakpoint here to count the rows of rdr
            {
```

My SQL command returns 482 rows which is verified in a SQL GUI. I run the exact same code and the `SqlDataReader` only returns 450 of them - is there a limit on the rows returned??

I haven't included the SQL statement as it's just a long `SELECT` statement with no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I'm not being patronising - but are you sure you're running it on the same database/instance/server?

Comment: @Bridge, you were correct. I never change my environment variables but I had to yesterday at the end of the day to run another program. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you're running it on the same database/instance/server?